# How to fix form DeprecatedWarning(s) before the update from Symfony 2.8 to Symfony 3.x?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

I have a small question about the update process from my symfony2.8 to symfony3.x.
I have a lot of deprecated warnings, which i want to fix before I'll start with the update.

But  I can't fix it, because it seems that some (new)feature are not available in the version 2.8. could it be?

for example:

```
   Accessing type "text" by its string name is deprecated since Symfony 2.8 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the fully-qualified type class name "Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType" instead. (3 times)  Show stack trace
```

that means, i should customize my form from:

```
->add('birthyear', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'Year of birth',
            'attr' => array('placeholder'=>'yyyy'),
            'required' => false,
    ))
```

to...

```
->add('birthyear', Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType:class, array(
            'label' => 'Year of birth',
            'attr' => array('placeholder'=>'yyyy'),
            'required' => false,
    ))
```

but this folder respectively path does not exist in my current version.

**Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType**

should I fix it after the update? or which workaround I have to do? I'm confused because in the Symfony doc is written "you should fix it before".

Thanks for the Feedback!

Comment: Your current version is 2.8?  TextType has been around for a long time.  You should not be using ::class when the class name is fully spelled out.  Or is there another problem?  No fundamental reason you cannot eliminate all the deprecation messages while staying on 2.8.

Comment: Thanks for your Feedback. I Installed the folder with the components new and now it is working!

Answer (score 1):

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;

->add('birthyear', TextType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Year of birth',
            'attr' => array('placeholder'=>'yyyy'),
            'required' => false,
    ))
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for your response! No it does not work. I tried it before I wrote my Question. I get the answer: Could not load type "General\CommonBundle\Form\TextType": class does not exist.

Comment: @helmi You left out the use statement.  But I see from a different comment you got it working.

Comment: Hei Thanks, sorry  it was a copy & paste error! Thanks you so much for your investet time!